# Spring Eureka with Token based mechanism

Tags: spring-cloud

I am having Eureka server, Spring cloud config server and Zuul in my environment. The Eureka server is protected with token based mechanism and expects a valid token to register/get applications etc..

I have defined DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs bean and injected ClientFilter instance into it at EurekaClient. The ClientFilter takes care of adding the token in Authorization header.

The DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs bean injected with ClientFilter is working fine in Config First Bootstrap approach when I connect to Spring cloud config server from zuul server.

But when I am trying to load the zuul configuration from Spring cloud config server using Discovery first approach, the ClientFilter is not working as expected. i.e., the application is trying to connect to eureka and looking for the config server id before the DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs bean get created.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What version are you using? We've clean up some issues where early initialization was happening.

Comment: I am using **spring-boot-starter 1.5.4.RELEASE**, spring-cloud-starter-eureka 1.2.5.RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-zuul 1.2.5.RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-config 1.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: Are you using the spring-cloud-dependencies bom?

Comment: Due comments text length constraint, I am splitting my reply to following 4 comments

Comment: I have updated my POM to have spring cloud dependencies as Dalston.SR2. Now I have **spring-boot-starter 1.5.4.RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-eureka 1.3.2.RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-zuul 1.3.2.RELEASE, spring-cloud-starter-config 1.3.2.RELEASE** and tested the application.

Comment: While application startup, 
1. DiscoveryClient object tried to get instance registry info from the eureka server (which is protected), got 403.<br/>
2. DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration refresh method called ConfigServerInstanceProvider.getConfigServerInstance() which returned "No instances found of configserver (CONFIGSERVER)".<br/>
3. The application tried to fetch config from default path (http://localhost:8888) and not able to locate PropertySource (since config server is running in different port).<br/>
4. Then application context loaded, all filters registered.

Comment: 5. DiscoveryClient shutdown happened,Unregistered and Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
6. Again, DiscoveryClient object initialized, tried to get instance registry info from the eureka server (which is protected), this time got valid response since the custom ClientFilter kicked in during the execution and added Authorization header. 
7. Registered the zuul instance in eureka.
8. Again, DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration refresh method called ConfigServerInstanceProvider.getConfigServerInstance() which returned "No instances found of configserver (CONFIGSERVER)".

Comment: In debug mode, I found that the ConfigServerInstanceProvider holds the old version of DiscoveryClient (created before step 4 which doesn't have any eureka instances information) but the DiscoveryClient created after step 4 has the eureka instances information (eurekaserver, CONFIGSERVER, zuulserver).

Any thoughts on why ConfigServerInstanceProvider doesn't have the updated DiscoveryClient object reference? What should be done to fix this issue?